# php - function echo a variable

Tags: php, html, function

I am currently writing some functions for a script I am working on. My problem is, that the way the content is generated is by a php variable.

So, to generate page contents, it must be like this:

```
$contents .="page content inside this";
```

If I make an `echo` like this:

```
echo "page content inside this";
```

then the echoed text will appear on top of the page. Therefore, I must use the `$contents.="";` in order to generate page content.

I am currently writing a function which can quickly generate checkboxes. My function looks like this:

```
function checkbox($name, $value, $checked){

    if($checked == 1){
        $checked = "checked"; 
    }else{ 
        $checked ="";
    }

    $contents.="<div class='roundedOne'>
   <input type='checkbox' value='$value' id='roundedOne' name='$name' $checked />
   <label for='roundedOne'></label>
  </div>";

}
```

When I call the function inside a page, nothing appears:

```
$contents.="
".checkbox("name","value","1")."
";
```

I can imagine that the reason nothing happens when I call the function, is that I've used `$contents` instead of `echo`, but unfortunately that is my only option, as the script is encrypted, so I cannot change the way `$contents` behave.

My question is, how can I make the function print with $contents?

Comment: instead of `$contents.=` just type `return` inside your function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare `$contents` as global before using it inside the function (not recommended) -

```
global $contents;
$contents.="<div class='roundedOne'>
     <input type='checkbox' value='$value' id='roundedOne' 
     name='$name' $checked />
     <label for='roundedOne'></label>
     </div>";
```

Or, better yet, you can generate the content from your function and then return it -

```
function checkbox($name, $value, $checked){

    if($checked == 1){
        $checked = "checked"; 
    }else{ 
        $checked ="";
    }

    return "<div class='roundedOne'>
       <input type='checkbox' value='$value' id='roundedOne' name='$name' 
       $checked />
       <label for='roundedOne'></label>
       </div>";        
}

$contents.= checkbox("name","value","1");
```

Also, you are changing the type of your `$checked` parameter inside the function. This style of coding is strongly discouraged. Try not to change the type of variable in this manner, it will save you from a lot of trouble.

Comment: Why is it dicouraged to change the parameter inside of the function? How could I do it then? I am fairly new to this language and I would love to learn the fall-groups.

Comment: @oliverbj: Consider this - you have a variable declared at the top of a long script which holds a numerical value. Now, after some line you change it to hold a string value. Suppose that later someone decided to change the code and add a numerical value with that variable (somewhere on the bottom of the script). He will not get accurate result because in this case that number will be concatenated as as string with the existing value. It will not generate an error. The maintainer will see that he is not getting an accurate result, but there is no error! These kinds of bugs are difficult to fix.

Comment: @oliverbj: For your method, you might not get into trouble because it's fairly simple. But then again, someone might run into trouble later if this function is being modified/extended....Anyway, you can use a different variable to hold your numeric value.

Answer (score 0):

Either use `global $contents` or at the end of your function `return $contents`

Answer (score 0):

What have you returned from the function. Return the string from the function . or use $content as global variable as oliverbj suggested

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your issue correctly.  Have you try using **global**?

```
<?php

$contents = "string string string";

function checkbox($name, $value, $checked){

    global $contents;

    if($checked == 1){
        $checked = "checked"; 
    }else{ 
        $checked ="";
    }

    $contents.="<div class='roundedOne'>
   <input type='checkbox' value='$value' id='roundedOne' name='$name' $checked />
   <label for='roundedOne'></label>
  </div>";

}

$contents.=" ".checkbox("name","value","1")." ";

echo $contents;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Return value of `$contents` from function.

Using that way you can get value of `$contents` inside your page.

like,

```
function checkbox($name, $value, $checked){

    if($checked == 1){
        $checked = "checked"; 
    }else{ 
        $checked ="";
    }

    $contents.="<div class='roundedOne'>
   <input type='checkbox' value='$value' id='roundedOne' name='$name' $checked />
   <label for='roundedOne'></label>
  </div>";
  return $contents;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are no returning value from your function.

So you didn't get anything as a response from `checkbox` function.

Just needs to `return $contents` from function and then echo that result will do for you.

```
function checkbox($name, $value, $checked){

    if($checked == 1){
        $checked = "checked"; 
    }else{ 
        $checked ="";
    }

    $contents.="<div class='roundedOne'>
   <input type='checkbox' value='$value' id='roundedOne' name='$name' $checked />
   <label for='roundedOne'></label>
  </div>";
  return $contents;
}
```

Then,

```
echo $contents;
```